# Android - GoogleApiClient - Not connecting on the load of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services

In Fragment `onCreateview`, connecting the `GoogleAPIClient`, but its not triggering `onConnected` call, but its firing if i go to another fragment and back.

> Couldnt find why? any help would be appreciated as i got stuck ?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                    .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                    .build(); 
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connected.");
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**`void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) Called to do initial
>   creation of a fragment.

You should add this **`onCreate`** section

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                    .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                    .build(); 

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
```

Then

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient .connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    }
```

It will be good approach checking **`onPause()`** State.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    }
```